# Using phone numbers from a text with preg_replace

Tags: javascript, php, preg-replace

I have no issue finding phone numbers within a text with preg_replace:

`$text = preg_replace("/(\+?[\d-\(\)\s]{8,25}[0-9]?\d)/", '<strong>$1</strong>', $text);`

However, I am working on a little function where the phone number will be obfuscated so I need the actual phone number, not the entire text.

The function looks like this:

```
$phone = '123-123-1234';

<script>
$(function(){
$('#number').click(function() {
$(this).find('span').text( $(this).data('last') );
});
});
</script>

<?php 
$trimmed_phone = substr($phone, 0, -5);
$last_digits = substr($phone, -5);

echo '<span id="number" data-last="'.$last_digits.'">'.$trimmed_phone.'<span>****<div class="showphone"> '.$lang['SHOW_NUMBER'].'</div></span></span>';
?>
```

It works great when I assign a phone number to it (as it's shown above). However I do not know how to implement it (how to extract phone numbers with preg_replace and then run them through the function) within a text that has both words and phone number(s).

Comment: Do you control the input pattern? In other words, can you ensure that someone doesn't enter an area code (e.g., +1, +44, +6721, etc.) or a party extension? Just plucking the last *n* characters of an uncontrolled string seems like playing with fire to me.

Comment: That's no an issue for me, currently. I'd like to make the function work first. Any ideas how?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Note that the pattern `(\+?[\d-()\s]{8,25}[0-9]?\d)` is a very broad match for a phonenumber and might also match for example `- - - - - 0`  Should something change on the client side or on the server side?